# program referring to courses

Tags: word-usage

If a private institution (that doesn't confer degrees) is offering recreational cooking classes, can these be collectively referred to as a program?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Are they individual classes, or a group of related classes that someone might take several of? Getting a degree (or not) is not an issue. The other clue is that they will call it a program.

Comment: They are individual courses (note that I am avoiding the word "class," as it is ambiguous between "course and "lesson"); a student typically pays to take one of these courses.

Answer (score 2):

In AmE, to call these recreational cooking classes a "program" would be a stretch of that word's meaning to the point of breaking.  A program typically has a defined structure with stages, and requirements, so that those leaving the program successfully can be expected to have acquired a specific range of knowledge and/or skills.  That scenario does not apply at all to recreational cooking classes. There is not even an attempt to measure and record "successful completion" with recreational classes.